# Using pushbutton to make Stepper motor rotate 90 degrees

Tags: arduino-uno-smd, stepper-motor

Using a 28BYJ-48 Motor with a ULN2000 Driver. The motor works fine since I can rotate it using serial input.
Pushbutton is connected properly, Can light up an led if I connect one.
I want the motor to rotate 90 degrees everytime I push the button. When I run the code below the LEDs on the driver just blink rapidly, when I press and hold the button they stop blinking, keeping the state they were on already. e.g. if the LED A on the board was on at the moment I press the button, It stays on. If it was off, It stays off. you get the Idea.

code used:

```
#include <Stepper.h>;


 // pushbutton pin
 const int buttonPin = 2;

 int STEPS = 32;
 Stepper stepper(STEPS,8,9,10,11);


//create a variable to store a counter and set it to 0
int counter = 0;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}


void loop()
{
 // local variable to hold the pushbutton states
  int buttonState;  

  //read the digital state of buttonPin with digitalRead() function and store the           //value in buttonState variable
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  //if the button is pressed increment counter and wait a tiny bit to give us some          //time to release the button
  if (buttonState == LOW) // light the LED
  {
    counter++;
    delay(150);
  }

  if(counter == 1)
    stepper.step(512);  // zero degrees
  //else reset the counter to 0 which resets thr servo to 0 degrees
  else
   counter = 0;
}
```

EDIT 1: Modifying the code @Matej gave me, I was able to debug the problem that was causing the stepper to not rotate. the code:

```
#include <Stepper.h>


// pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin = 2;

const int STEPS = 32;
Stepper stepper(STEPS, 8, 9, 10, 11);
int val = 2048;

//create a variable to store a counter and set it to 0
int counter = 0;

unsigned long last_button_time = 0;   //for aving last millis 



void setup(){
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000);
}


void loop(){
  bool buttonState;   // local variable to hold the pushbutton states

  //read the digital state of buttonPin with digitalRead() function and store the           //value in buttonState variable
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //if the button is pressed incremen counter and wait a tiny bit to give us some          //time to release the button
  if(buttonState == HIGH && millis() - last_button_time > 200){ // light the LED  
    last_button_time = millis();
    counter = 1;
    Serial.println(counter);
  }

  if (counter == 1) {
    Serial.println("Please Write the desired angle");
    val = Serial.parseInt();
    delay(5000);
    counter = 0;
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("Stepping: ");
    Serial.print(val);
    stepper.step(val);
    counter = 0;
    Serial.println(counter);
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("ERROR LOOPING THROUGH IF STATEMENT");
    }
  }

}
```

The Serial output looks like this:

```
1
Please Write the desired angle
Stepping: 
00
1
Please Write the desired angle
Stepping: 
20480
1
Please Write the desired angle
Stepping: 
20480
```

please note that In the first attempt, I wrote "2048" in Serial input to define the value of the integer (val), and nothing happened. in the second and third attempt, I also wrote 2048 (0 at the end is the counter variable) and the motor started shaking, but it didn't rotate.

Comment: i don't see any code that moves the servo 90 degrees

Comment: I'm moving a stepper motor, not a servo  ^__^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edtied few things in your code. I am not sure if `LOW` value is correct, so I replaced it with `HIGH`. Second thing is timing. I removed all `delay()` functions instead of it you can see usage of `millis()`. That's for handling interval between button press and button release - second part of `if` will check if last time of button press is bigger than `200ms`, if yes, move stepper. Last things is stepping. You can see here `stepper.step(STEPS/4);`. `STEPS` is variable which you declared on the top of code. It's called steps per revolution, one revolution is `360°` so `90°` will be `STEPS/4`.

Here is the code, read it and test it:

```
#include <Stepper.h>;


// pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin = 2;

const int STEPS = 32;
Stepper stepper(STEPS, 8, 10, 9, 11);


//create a variable to store a counter and set it to 0
int counter = 0;

unsigned long last_button_time = 0;   //for aving last millis 



void setup(){
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000)
}


void loop(){
  bool buttonState;   // local variable to hold the pushbutton states

  //read the digital state of buttonPin with digitalRead() function and store the           //value in buttonState variable
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  //if the button is pressed increment counter and wait a tiny bit to give us some          //time to release the button
  if(buttonState == HIGH && millis() - last_button_time > 200){ // light the LED  
    last_button_time = millis();
    counter++;
    stepper.step(STEPS/4);    //90° degrees 
  }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( in my old code the LEDs on the Driver where blinking when you weren't pressing the button, in your code they blink when I press the button.

Comment: @MTXShiftGames And that's correct when leds on the driver board blinks only during button press, right?

Comment: I and you both forgot to do `stepper.setSpeed(1000);` but that didn't help. the LEDs on the driver blink when I push the button but nothing happens. I forgot to mention I have the motor plugged into a breadboard and powered by a breadboard Power supply, in case that makes a difference.

EDIT: Please Check Question EDIT.

Comment: @MTXShiftGames And does motor work with example? Are steps per revolution 32 correct?

Comment: yup it works. I have a program that rotates the motor based on serial input and the STEPS/Revolution is defined as 32 and that works.

Comment: @MTXShiftGames Can you, please, post this code somewhere? For example on pastebin.com

Comment: Here it is: [link](https://pastebin.com/erfCNHri)

Comment: @MTXShiftGames I can see only difference in this `stepper.setSpeed(1000);`. If you put this to the setup(), does it work?

Comment: I already did, Can you please check the updated code in my question? Please you helped me a lot, I wasn't getting anywhere

Comment: @MTXShiftGames Oh, look at the pins on pastebin and pins here. They are swapped.

Comment: @MTXShiftGames I edited my answer. Try code now.

Comment: You are Such a legend, Man. it's finally working! Thank you so so Much.

Comment: @MTXShiftGames Great! You're welcome. :)

Answer (score -1):

**Just a quick Tweak:**

Please note while using Adruino, using "INPUT" mode without enabling the internal pull-up resistor, you need to ensure that the switch is connected properly and that you have external pull-up or pull-down resistors in your circuit. In the code you provided, you haven't included the necessary external pull-up resistor.

To tweak and fix the code, here a simple quick option:

Usage of **"INPUT_PULLUP"** mode instead of **"INPUT"**:

This is the simpler and recommended approach. Just change the line:

```
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); to pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

It will enable the internal pull-up resistor of the Arduino, eliminating the need for external resistors in your circuit.

Here is quick fixed code:

```
#include <Stepper.h>;
// Using Stepper Motor to rotate 90 degree
// Reference: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61260/using-pushbutton-to-make-stepper-motor-rotate-90-degrees

// pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin = 2;

const int STEPS = 32;
Stepper stepper(STEPS, 8, 10, 9, 11);


//create a variable to store a counter and set it to 0
int counter = 0;

unsigned long last_button_time = 0;   //for having last millis 


void setup(){
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000)
}


void loop(){
  bool buttonState;   // local variable to hold the pushbutton states

  //read the digital state of buttonPin with digitalRead() function and store the           //value in buttonState variable
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  //if the button is pressed increment counter and wait a tiny bit to give us some          //time to release the button
  if(buttonState == HIGH && millis() - last_button_time > 200){ // light the LED  
    last_button_time = millis();
    counter++;
    stepper.step(STEPS/4);    //90° degrees 
  }
}
```

Connection Setup:

To connect an external switch to an Arduino using the internal pull-up resistor, ie. using "INPUT_PULLUP" instead of just "INPUT" in your above code, you will need to make the following connections:

1. Connect one terminal of the switch to the digital input pin on the Arduino. Let's assume you're using pin 2 for this example.
2. Connect the other terminal of the switch to ground (GND) on the Arduino.

With this connection setup, you're essentially creating a circuit where the switch is connected between the digital input pin and ground. When the switch is not pressed, the internal pull-up resistor will pull the input pin's voltage to a high level (logic HIGH). When the switch is pressed, it will connect the input pin to ground, resulting in a low level (logic LOW).

Alternatively, In case, you use "INPUT" instead "INPUT_PULLUP" which would not be a best approach here. You may follow the below example:

Here's an example of the circuit and code using an external pull-up resistor:

Circuit:

1. Connect one terminal of the switch to the digital input pin on the Arduino.
2. Connect the other terminal of the switch to the junction point between a pull-up resistor (e.g., 10K ohm) and Vcc (5V).

Code Example:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;  // Pin connected to the external switch

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH);  // Enable internal pull-up resistor
}

void loop() {
  // Read the state of the button
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Perform your desired actions based on the button state
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    // The button is pressed
    // Do something...
  } else {
    // The button is not pressed
    // Do something else...
  }
}
```

Kindly note to add below line of code inside void setup() to enable internal pull-up resistor as shown in above code
i.e.  **digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH);**  // Enable internal pull-up resistor

hope that helps. Great job Guyz, Happy coding.